# Writing the output of Get-NetTCPConnection to an array - no output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write the values of the PowerShell cmdlet `Get-NetTCPConnection` to an array but nothing is being written to the list.

```
$list= @()

$outputs = Get-NetTCPConnection 

foreach ($output in $outputs) {
    $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        TheLocalAddress  = "EMPTY"
        TheLocalPort     = "EMPTY"
        TheRemoteAddress = "EMPTY"
        TheRemotePort    = "EMPTY"
    }

    $obj.TheLocalAddress  = $output.LocalAddress
    $obj.TheLocalPort     = $output.LocalPort
    $obj.TheRemoteAddress = $output.RemoteAddress
    $obj.TheRemotePort    = $output.RemotePort

    $list += $obj
}
$list
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Is there more to this that you've omitted?

Comment: Hmm... this didn't work for me but I have run this again now and it has! The array was empty.. consider this cone closed off. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix `The` isn't required for the properties, why not use

```
$list = Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort
```

Or a more efficient `[PSCustomObject]` ?

```bsh
$list = foreach ($Conn in Get-NetTCPConnection) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TheLocalAddress  = $Conn.LocalAddress
        TheLocalPort     = $Conn.LocalPort
        TheRemoteAddress = $Conn.RemoteAddress
        TheRemotePort    = $Conn.RemotePort
    }
}
$list
```